# Multiline Extraction Issue from table in Python

Tags: python

```
import camelot
import pandas as pd
import regex as re

filename = 'sample.pdf'
page_number = 64
tables = camelot.read_pdf(filename, flavor='stream', table_areas=["0,4842,4595,0"], pages=str(page_number))
df = tables[0].df

test_values = []
# df.to_csv('sample.csv')
headline_row_index = None
for index, row in enumerate(df.values):
    row_text = ' '.join(row).strip()
    pattern = r'(?i)[^\w]*headline\s*earnings\s*per\s*share.*\d+|headline\s*earnings\s*per\s*share\s*\(cents\)\s*basic.*\d+|headline\s*earnings\s*per\s*share\s*\(basic\s*and\s*diluted\).*\d+'
    match = re.search(pattern, row_text)
    if match:
        matched_text = match.group()
        print(matched_text)
        headline_row_index = index      
        break
print(headline_row_index)

# Combine "headline earning per share" rows into one entity
if headline_row_index is not None:
    headline_earning_per_share = ''
    if len(df.iloc[headline_row_index]) > 0:  # Check if the row is not empty
        cells = df.iloc[headline_row_index].values.tolist()
        headline_earning_per_share = ' '.join(cells)
        # Concatenate with the next row if available
        next_row_index = headline_row_index + 1
        if next_row_index < len(df):
            next_row = df.iloc[next_row_index].values.tolist()
            cells = [cell if cell != '-' else '' for cell in next_row]
            headline_earning_per_share += ' '.join(cells)
        else:
            # No match in the first row, check the next row for matches and value
            for next_row_index in range(headline_row_index + 1, len(df)):
                next_row = df.iloc[next_row_index].values.tolist()
                next_row_text = ' '.join(next_row).strip()
                if re.search('(?i)[^\w]*headline\s*earnings\s*per\s*share.*\d+|headline\s*earnings\s*per\s*share\s*\(cents\)\s*basic.*\d+|headline\s*earnings\s*per\s*share\s*\(basic\s*and\s*diluted\).*\d+|headline\s*earnings\s*per\s*share\s*\(cents\).*\s*', next_row_text):
                    cells = [cell if cell != '-' else '' for cell in next_row]
                    headline_earning_per_share = ' '.join(cells)
                    break


# Find the indices of the "total cents" columns
total_cents_columns = []
for index, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    column_text = ' '.join(df.iloc[:, index].values.tolist())
    if re.search('(?i)[^\w]*total[^\w]*cents|total', column_text.strip()):
        total_cents_columns.append(index)
for index in total_cents_columns:
    value = df.iloc[headline_row_index, index]
    test_values.append(value)
print(test_values)
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFi4o.png)

Here Headline earnings per share (cents)
Basic is on different line so that it's giving headline_row_index as None
For some file the words mention in single files in that case it is extracting properly but files like above are not extracted

How to append it and be in generalized way

By using above code I'm getting headline_row_index as None it should append that two line if it finds it pattern in regex